How can I track changes in database using postgresql as my database server
I'm building an CRUD application using fast API and now i want to version the data such as what is the current version of the data and what are the previous versions
of that data.
For example let us say i have an user table and i will use an history table of this user table (clone of user table) and now i will create another table named as address table and same i will create history table of this (clone of address).
Now I will track tables using the history table such as when updates are happening i will insert the old data into their respective history tables and then perform update operation in the main table.
Now my question is that an user can have two address or more, so i want to track this addresses like before this user had this addresses and now after inserting this many are the addresses of that user. I have implemented but it wont giving me the expected output.
I'm expecting that the address insertion are tracked using versioning and show that in version 1 this was addresses for that user and after insertion the current version has this much addresses
These are the CRUD's API files
from models.User_model import *
from models.database_history import *
from fastapi import FastAPI,Depends,APIRouter,Query,HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel,validator
from schemas.User_schemas import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from database import get_db

router = APIRouter()

def insert_into_history(db, table, old_data, operation_type="UPDATE"):
    if table == Users:
        latest_version = db.query(func.max(UsersHistory.version)).filter(UsersHistory.User_id == old_data.User_id).scalar() or 0
        history = UsersHistory(
            User_id=old_data.User_id,
            Name=old_data.Name,
            Age=old_data.Age,
            Gender=old_data.Gender,
            operation_type=operation_type,
            updated_at=datetime.utcnow(),
            version=latest_version+1,
        )
    elif table == Address:
        latest_version = db.query(func.max(AddressHistory.version)).filter(AddressHistory.User_id == old_data.User_id).scalar() or 0
        history = AddressHistory(
            Address_id=old_data.Address_id,
            User_id=old_data.User_id,
            House_no=old_data.House_no,
            Street_name=old_data.Street_name,
            Landmark=old_data.Landmark,
            Zipcode=old_data.Zipcode,
            Address_type=old_data.Address_type,
            operation_type=operation_type,
            updated_at=datetime.utcnow(),
            version=latest_version + 1,
        )
    elif table == Bank:
        latest_version = db.query(func.max(BankHistory.version)).filter(BankHistory.User_id == old_data.User_id).scalar() or 0
        history = BankHistory(
            Bank_id=old_data.Bank_id,
            User_id=old_data.User_id,
            Bank_name=old_data.Bank_name,
            IFSC_code=old_data.IFSC_code,
            Account_number=old_data.Account_number,
            Account_type=old_data.Account_type,
            operation_type=operation_type,
            updated_at=datetime.utcnow(),
            version=latest_version + 1,
        )
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported table type passed to insert_into_history")
    db.add(history)
    db.commit()

# POST API To add all details
@router.post("/addUsers")
async def addUser(user: UserCreate,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        # create and save User
        newUser = Users(**user.dict())
        db.add(newUser)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(newUser)
        return {"message": "Successfully added User"}
    except Exception as e:
        db.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500,detail=str(e))

@router.post("/addAdrress")
async def add_address(address: AddressCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        # First check user exists or not
        user_exists = db.query(Users).filter(Users.User_id == address.User_id).first()
        address_before = []
        if not user_exists:
            address_before = []
        else:
            current_addresses = db.query(Address).filter(Address.User_id == address.User_id).all()
            addresses_before = [
                {
                    "Address_id": addr.Address_id,
                    "User_id":addr.User_id,
                    "House_no": addr.House_no,
                    "Street_name": addr.Street_name,
                    "Landmark": addr.Landmark,
                    "Zipcode": addr.Zipcode,
                    "Address_type": addr.Address_type,
                }
                for addr in current_addresses
            ]

        # add the new addresses
        new_address = Address(**address.dict())
        db.add(new_address)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(new_address)

        # record this changes in our history table
        for addr in current_addresses:
            insert_into_history(db, Address, addr,operation_type="INSERT")

        # fetch the newly inserted addresses
        updated_addresses = db.query(Address).filter(Address.User_id == address.User_id).all()
        addresses_after = [
            {
                "Address_id": addr.Address_id,
                "User_id": addr.User_id,
                "House_no": addr.House_no,
                "Street_name": addr.Street_name,
                "Landmark": addr.Landmark,
                "Zipcode": addr.Zipcode,
                "Address_type": addr.Address_type,
            }
            for addr in updated_addresses
        ]

        # return before address and after address
        return {
            "message": "Successfully added Address",
            "Addresses_before": addresses_before,
            "Addresses_after": addresses_after,
        }
    except Exception as e:
        db.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

@router.post("/addBank")
async def add_bank(bank: BankCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        new_bank = Bank(**bank.dict())
        db.add(new_bank)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(new_bank)
        return {"message": "Successfully added Bank details"}
    except Exception as e:
        db.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))




@router.put("/updateUser/{user_id}")
async def update_user(user_id: int, user: UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        existing_user = db.query(Users).filter(Users.User_id == user_id).first()
        if not existing_user:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")

        # Insert old data into history
        insert_into_history(db, Users, existing_user)

        # Update the main table
        existing_user.Name = user.Name
        existing_user.Age = user.Age
        existing_user.Gender = user.Gender
        db.commit()
        return {"message": "User updated successfully"}
    except Exception as e:
        db.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))


# PUT API: Update Address
@router.put("/updateAddress/{address_id}")
async def update_address(address_id: str, address: AddressCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        existing_address = db.query(Address).filter(Address.Address_id == address_id).first()
        if not existing_address:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Address not found")

        # Insert old data into history
        insert_into_history(db, Address, existing_address)

        # Update the main table
        existing_address.House_no = address.House_no
        existing_address.Street_name = address.Street_name
        existing_address.Landmark = address.Landmark
        existing_address.Zipcode = address.Zipcode
        existing_address.Address_type = address.Address_type
        db.commit()
        return {"message": "Address updated successfully"}
    except Exception as e:
        db.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))


# PUT API: Update Bank Details
@router.put("/updateBank/{bank_id}")
async def update_bank(bank_id: str, bank: BankCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        existing_bank = db.query(Bank).filter(Bank.Bank_id == bank_id).first()
        if not existing_bank:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Bank details not found")

        # Insert old data into history
        insert_into_history(db, Bank, existing_bank)

        # Update the main table
        existing_bank.Bank_name = bank.Bank_name
        existing_bank.IFSC_code = bank.IFSC_code
        existing_bank.Account_number = bank.Account_number
        existing_bank.Account_type = bank.Account_type
        db.commit()
        return {"message": "Bank details updated successfully"}
    except Exception as e:
        db.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

# get Address of specify user
@router.get("/getAddress")
async def get_address(user_id: int,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        address = db.query(Address).filter(Address.User_id==user_id).all()
        # store all address of the user
        all_user_address = []
        for addressed in address:
            all_user_address.append({
                "Address_id": addressed.Address_id,
                "House_no": addressed.House_no,
                "Street_name": addressed.Street_name,
                "Landmark": addressed.Landmark,
                "Zipcode": addressed.Zipcode,
                "Address_type": addressed.Address_type
            })
        return {"All_address": all_user_address}
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500,detail=str(e))

# get Bank details of specify user
@router.get("/getBankDetails")
async def get_bank_details(user_id: int,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        bank = db.query(Bank).filter(Bank.User_id==user_id).all()
        # store all address of the user
        all_user_bank = []
        for banks in bank:
            all_user_bank.append({
                "Bank_id": banks.Bank_id,
                "Bank_name": banks.Bank_name,
                "IFSC_code": banks.IFSC_code,
                "Account_number": banks.Account_number,
                "Account_type": banks.Account_type,
            })
        return {"All_address": all_user_bank}
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500,detail=str(e))


# ========================== DELETE APIs ========================== #

# DELETE API: Delete User
@router.delete("/deleteUser/{user_id}")
async def delete_user(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        existing_user = db.query(Users).filter(Users.User_id == user_id).first()
        user_address = db.query(Address).filter(Address.User_id==user_id).first()
        user_bank = db.query(Bank).filter(Bank.User_id==user_id).first()
        if not existing_user:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")

        # Insert into history before deleting
        insert_into_history(db, Users, existing_user, operation_type="DELETE")
        insert_into_history(db, Address, user_address, operation_type="DELETE")
        insert_into_history(db, Bank, user_bank, operation_type="DELETE")

        db.delete(existing_user)
        db.commit()
        return {"message": "User deleted successfully"}
    except Exception as e:
        db.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))



You can do this on the database level instead of the application level: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Temporal_Extensions - I also recommend using a trigger if you can't use extensions, so that everything is handled on the server side instead of having to special case every operation in your database layer (and if you need to do it in your application layer, hook into SQLAlchemy signals / events instead so that you don't have to do it manually every time you do something to your data.
